# Checking return departure time

Tags: air-travel

I am on vacation (Mauritius) with a (Swedish) travel bureau which offers hotel packages but I only have a “flight chair” without hotel and therefore have no contact with the bureau´s on site representatives. Ideally I should have made contact with the local representatives on arrival for the sole purpose of getting their phone number to check the return flight schedule 24 hours before departure but I missed that. However, I can reach the airport departures on internet.

The local representative can only be reached by going a considerable distance to a hotel where they might have a folder available with phone numbers, or possibly interviewing other guests. They have my phone and email and in the few cases there have been a change of departure I have always been alerted on commercial flights by email and sms.

The departure is tomorrow and the flight (TOM 767) is scheduled on time. Is there any risk for me here – or additional value in contacting the local representative?

Comment: Contact the airline direct and check on flight status and reconfirming if necessary.  Your hotel should have a list of local phone numbers for airlines serving the island (if not they should know how to call directory information ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have booked a flight only, it should specify the actual flight, and in this case information from the airline should be sufficient (if your booking is "confirmed").

It would be different if you had actually booked a package (flight+hotel), as they could possibly switch you to another flight, but in this case you would generally not have been informed of the flight number.

Have you tried using the Thomson Airlines website's "Manage my booking" feature? It should let you know everything about your booking.

Comment: Thanks. that is what I settled for in the end.  I couldn't find a phone listing as suggested by Tom above. They might perhaps not be permanently staffed at the airport.